# Tkinter: how to open a Toplevel window from another script

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

I'm a newbie in programming and I'm struggling a bit (a lot actually) with my first "program". Here's what I did:
since I want the code not to be too long, I want to split it in two files. In the first one I call the main window, where I put a button. If I click this button, I run the second script, that should hide the main window and make appear a new window (toplevel). The problem is that if I click the button nothing happens.
A thing I noticed is that if in the second script I add the strings "if **name**=="**main**":   main.mainloop()", then this new window does appear, but a second main window appears too, as if I re-runned the main code.

Script one:

```
from tkinter import *
import os
main=Tk()
def sw():
   os.system("python3 ./script_two.py")
my_button=Button(main,text="NEW",command=sw)
my_button.grid(row=0,column=0)
if__name__="__main__":
   main.mainloop()
```

Script two:

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import script_one
script_one.main.withdraw()
second_window=Toplevel()
def Close():
   second_window.destroy()
   script_one.main.deiconify()
second_button = Button(second_window,text="Exit",command=Close)
second_button.grid(row=0,column=0)
```

If I put together the scripts (inserting the code of "script_two" in 'def sw()'), I get exactly what I want, but if I split them as showed, I get the problem.
Obviously for a code this short it would be easier and faster to write a single script, what I actually have is a longer code, but the problem is the same.
Any idea? Thank you very much

Comment: Why are you using `os.system("python3 ./script_two.py")` instead of `import script_two`?

Comment: it is better to do just what @TheLizzard said but I suggest that You first call `os.system(f'cd {os.getcwd()}')` and after that just `os.system('python3 script.py')` tho maybe You need to navigate from current working directory too so just add to the first `.system` call like: `os.system(f"cd {os.getcwd()}\sub_dir")` or more if needed

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answers. I tried to do as @TheLizzard said, but there is still a  problem. I can't use `import script_two` at the beginning of the script because it would make script_two running immediatly, and I don't want that, so i put `import script_two` in `def sw()`, and it seems to work fine.
The problem is, I have to call `import script_one` at the beginning of script_two, but in this way the script_one re-runs (I have two main windows). How can I avoid that?

Comment: @ALAF Why are you importing `script_one`? It's bad practise to import your main script from a script imported by the main one.

Comment: #TheLizzard how can I call variables from `script_one` if I don't import it? In this case, if I don't import `script_one`, then `script_one.main.deiconify()` gives me an error (name 'main' is not defined), and the same goes if I want to call other variables. Is there a way to read the variables from a different script without running the script?

Comment: @ALAF In that case it's much easier to keep them as 1 file. Importing a file runs that file and that is what setts up the variables. So you can't get the main script variables from the second one unless you create a function in the second script and pas them as arguments.

Comment: I see, I really hoped to be able to split the code in multiple scripts. Nevermind, it means I'll have to keep the script as much organized and clean as possible. Thank you a lot for your help and for the quick answers (Matiiss too of course)